Make a table SQLite in db.schema.table
I need a table in sqlite that returns data when queried with:
select * from db.schema.table
This is for testing of some other code that otherwise calls a databricks cluster / postgresdb where there are these schemas. The other DB is not under my control so the select query cannot be changed.
I don't want to mock the DB response as that can introduce other mistakes. Are there any plugins or modifications of sqlite that enable this?
For completeness the current approach is:
mock_db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = mock_db.cursor()
cursor.execute("ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS dbname")
# cursor.execute("CREATE SCHEMA schemaname") # This bit is not supported
cursor.create('CREATE TABLE dbname.tablename ("Column1" TEXT, "Column2"  INTEGER)')
mock_db.commit()
cursor.close() 



I need a table in sqlite that returns data when queries with: select * from db.schema.table

You can't do that, sorry.
Sqlite does not use 3-part names; instead it uses 1-part names in most cases - and only uses 2-part names when you have attached multiple database files in the same session, in which case the "schema" part is the alias of the attached database:
From their docs:

Tables in an attached database can be referred to using the syntax schema-name.table-name. If the name of the table is unique across all attached databases and the main and temp databases, then the schema-name prefix is not required. If two or more tables in different databases have the same name and the schema-name prefix is not used on a table reference, then the table chosen is the one in the database that was least recently attached.


By-way of explanation, you wrote:

This is for testing of some other code that otherwise calls a databricks cluster / postgresdb where there are these schemas. The other DB is not under my control so the select query cannot be changed.

The real problem here is that you're assuming you can substitute one SQL-based RDBMS for seemingly any other; this is an incorrect assumption because (excepting only the most trivial SELECT and INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements) SQL statements are not portable between RDBMS engines/vendors.
(Yes, "officially" the SQL language is defined by the vendor-neutral ISO SQL committee - and all vendors claiming to support SQL should all meet some sensible minimum compliance threshold w.r.t. the latest SQL revision - unfortunately the reality is the opposite: the ISO SQL  standard and specification is closer to a set of guidelines from which the vendors only pick whatever suits them the most to implement. I'll agree that today in 2024 there's significantly more source-level compatibility between, say, Oracle 23ai and MSSQL 2022 than there was in the 1990s between IBM Db2 and MS Access 97, but there will always be some important platform-difference (e.g. data-types, authX, megayacht status, etc) that'll ensure you'll need to maintain separate hardcoded queries for each RDBMS.


Are there any plugins or modifications of sqlite that enable this?

If you're in a pinch, you could just do a String.Replace (or a Regex if necessary) to convert 3-part names to 1-part names as-appropriate - but that should be a last-resort if you're unable to modify your program to generate or use queries/statements appropriate (and correct) for each RDBMS you're targeting.

Unit tests run against sqlite, integration tests against the correct DBs (though their dev versions, so the data can't be used to test the logic of the functions). And please don't mention Oracle SQL shenanigans it gives me ptsd :)

@ic_fl2 Oracle may have given you PTSD - which is bad enough, but Oracle just now bankrupted the largest city-council in Europe, lol)
